# Transaction is not active and execute query taking a long time in Jboss

Tags: java, oracle, jboss, transactions, atg

We are using ATG for an eCommerce Site. Now we're using some scheduler to fetch the data from the oracle DB. Today we got a "transaction is not active" exception.

We increased the timeout from 300 (default) to 3000. Now we are not getting this exception but it is taking so long to execute the query. Any pointers? While executing this query through sqlserver it is taking much less time.

Exception:

> 2014-07-10 21:17:41,888 ERROR [STDERR] CONTAINER:atg.repository.RepositoryException; SOURCE:org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -75f3a39c:ca13:53bf2cee:6051 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: -75f3a39c:ca13:53bf2cee:6051 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >)
>   2014-07-10 21:17:41,888 ERROR [STDERR]     at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItemDescriptor.executeQuery(GSAItemDescriptor.java:7638)
>   2014-07-10 21:17:41,888 ERROR [STDERR]     at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAView.executeUncachedQuery(GSAView.java:332)
>   2014-07-10 21:17:41,888 ERROR [STDERR]     at atg.repository.query.QueryCache.executeUncachedQuery(QueryCache.java:693

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the SQL Debugger on the `/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/dynamo/service/jdbc/JTDataSource` component.  This will give you the exact SQL that is being generated by your RQL statement which is often not that efficient.  **Warning** this will generate a lot of debug statements so only do it for a short time and never in a production environment. Suggest you then check that you have indexes on the relevant columns and tables.

Alternatively, you can also try enabling the ATG performance monitor from the dynamo admin page and adding `PerformanceMonitor` to your code code.  An example of how you do this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0702addingperformancemonitormethodst01.html).